# How can i change the backgroud color of button?

Tags: php, html, css

I want background in green. Here is my code-

```
<div class="pB20 pL70">
    <div class="btnGreen">
       <span> 
          <a>
             <input id="Login"  background-color: = "#698B22"; name="Login" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" value="Login"  type="submit">
          </a>
        </span>
     </div>
  <div class="fLeft pL10">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Here is a snap shot.

[image: Login BUtton]

Comment: paste your code button please

Comment: Looks like an image or gradient. Check up the style declarations for `#btnGreen`.

Comment: If you want to check the gray, just wrap `background-color` in style. `style='background-color:#698B22;`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `<button>submit</button>` and style with css like

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], button {
 background: #698B22;}
```

that should give you desired output.

Comment: You can use a button and style it according to your needs and still get the effect you looking for.You can name it what ever you want in your case it is named Login and you can do the styling in your css as per my example.

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax error in your button code.

Instead of this:

```
<input id="Login"  background-color: = "#698B22"; name="Login" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" value="Login"  type="submit">
```

Use like this:

```
 <input id="Login" name="Login" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" style="background-color:#698B22;" value="Login"  type="submit">
```

Comment: thannks sir for this help

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done through CSS. Please check the below the code and try whether it helps you or not.

**Here is the button html:**

```
<input id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
```

**Here it's CSS**

```
input#login {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #698B22;
    border: 1px solid #698B22;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input#login:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #207D36;
    border: 1px solid #207D36;
}
```

Please give it a try and let me know through linking the answer :) Happy coding :)